# git commit the wrong filename first letter uppercase

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

The git don't commit the correct filename first letter uppercase. In my workspace, I have a User.js, but in the git status, it shows user.js, and no matter how many time I change and commit User.js, the git still treats it as user.js and pushed to the server Where the app not executing because the incorrect filename. How to change the user.js in the git to User.js to match my working filename?

Comment: Are you on a Windows system?

Comment: @Daniel I am on a mac system.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use git to rename it or it wouldn't know:

```
git mv user.js User.js
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv